# Fast reading of files bigger than memory in c

Tags: c, file, file-io

I want to read lines from several Files and not line per line.
The files don't fit in memory, so I have to read from disk.
What would be the best way in C to read specific lines from several files with the best peformance?

Example:

- Line 1 from file 4
- Line 5 from file 2
- Line 5 from file 4 .......

Comment: Is the sequence in which the lines are output critical?  Does the specification require lines from each file in sequence (so, for example, the next line of output could not be 'Line 1 from file 4')?
You're likely to have read each file sequentially (possibly reading different files in parallel) to find where the line endings are.  I assume there's no convenient 'all lines in a given file are the same length' property that can be used to speed up access.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you could read and memory map the file in multi-megabytes chunks using the [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) syscall, possibly with [madvise(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/madvise.2.html) and perhaps (in another thread) [readhahead(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/readahead.2.html) syscall.

But the bottleneck is probably your hardware. Consider using SSD or very fast disks.

<sub>If you are interested in line boundaries, you should manage them (and memoize them) explicitly, perhaps remembering some offsets of some newline characters.</sub>

Comment: Actually, `mmap` is often _slower_ than `read`/`write` due to TLB thrashing.  Or, in the words of a certain kernel programmer, [Yes, memory is "slow", but dammit, so is mmap](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0802.0/1496.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Linux, or Windows, you can create a file mapping of the file. That won't put into memory and will give you a fast access to the files' buffer.

In linux you can check the man for "mmap".

In Windows I don't remember, but you can google it: file mapping on windows.

About reading line by line, you just can use fscanf or implement your own function, remember: read until "\n" in linux, and "\r\n" in windows.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, fscanf is only for FILE reading. I wanted to refer: sscanf. Also, don't lost from mind to implement your own read function. GoodLuck!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not reading the file.
Your problem is knowing which part of the file to read.

For this, you will have to prepare in advance an index table with the position of the beginning of every line.

You can, of course, construct it in lazy manner, then Nth line is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which file system you are using, but almost surely it will not be able to automatically keep track of where the line breakers are placed in the memory reserved to the file.

That's to say that in order to have a way to fast access the file at a specific line, you need to build an index of the lines, and if there isn't any known propriety of the files you are dealing with, you will need to fully scan the files at least once to build such indexes.

Obviously, if the files are greater than the system RAM, you will need to implement a wise memory management while performing the scan needed to build your index.

After the index is created, you will simply access the only section of the memory you want read.